# How to allow auth users to send newsletters from django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm implementing a newsletter app for a company website. My goal is to allow the 'future' website administrator to fire a newsletter directly from the admin.

For doing so, I wrote the following code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class NewsletterSubscription(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Iscritto Newsletter'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Iscritti Newsletter'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
        ('Pubblicata', 'Pubblicata')
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField()
    email = models.ManyToManyField(NewsletterSubscription)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject
```

I'd like to know if is possible to add to the *NewsletterAdminForm* a sort of button which allows to fire the email.

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import NewsletterSubscription, Newsletter
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget

class NewsletterSubscriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'datetime', )

class NewsletterAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = '__all__'

class NewsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsletterAdminForm

admin.site.register(NewsletterSubscription, NewsletterSubscriptionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Newsletter, NewsletterAdmin)
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To get a button in the admin panel you can simply create a method which will return the html:

```
class NewsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    readonly_fields = ['send_mails']

    def send_mails(self, obj):
        url_red = 'url_of_your_view_to_send_mails'
        return format_html(
            '<a class="button" href="{}">Send</a>&nbsp;',
            url_red,
        )
```

This will then get rendered as a button in the admin page which will send a GET request to the url supplied of the view, where you can define all the logic and send mails . Do include this custom field in the *fields* attribute.

Hope it helps.